# script that uses functions to set years to months, days, hours, seconds

Tags: powershell

```
[int]$a = Read-Host 'what is your age ?'
[string]$b = Read-Host 'Do you want your age in days,seconds,minutes or months'
```

So the user has to choose which he wants back and i have to use functions to set the years to what he chose if have no idea how to do this i'm pretty new to powershell

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

To take this info you must from current time subtract  time "your age" ago. And then select needed fiels for users choice.

```
[int]$a = Read-Host 'what is your age ?'
[string]$b = Read-Host 'Do you want your age in days,seconds,minutes or months'
if($b -eq "months"){
$a |select @{n="Month";e={$a*12}}}
if($b -eq "days"){
(get-date)-(get-date).AddYears(-$a) |select totaldays}
if($b -eq "minutes"){
(get-date)-(get-date).AddYears(-$a) |select totalminutes}
if($b -eq "seconds"){
(get-date)-(get-date).AddYears(-$a) |select totalseconds}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
# start of the code
switch ($b){
  "days" {(get-date).addyears(-$a).totaldays}
  "minutes" {(get-date).addyears(-$a).totalminutes}
  "seconds" {(get-date).addyears(-$a).totalseconds}
  "months" {((get-date).addyears(-$a).totaldays) / 30}
}
```

Comment: @koen If you need to be more precise, the average number of days in a month in the Gregorian calendar is 30.436875